# How to set TempDB parameter to autogrow in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

When I am executing script it shows `TempDB` is full backup some space for transaction log.

My transaction log is 1mb, my database is in the simple recovery model

`TempDB` size is 871 mb and hard disk free size is 33 Gb

Any one have idea how I can increase my `TempDB` size?

Comment: Have you [looked at the official MSDN documentation on TempDB???](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To view a database
In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
Expand Databases, right-click the database to view, and then click **Properties**.
In the **Database Properties** dialog box, select a page to view the corresponding information. For example, select the **Files** page to view data and log file information.

Then you will see something like `By 20 percent, restricted growth`. You can edit it by clicking button next to it.

[If you need query based support](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9452.tempdb.aspx)

Comment: you have any documentation which shows the screen shots?? i am new to SQL,

Comment: Do you know how to go to Database in  MS SQL server Studio? If yes, the Right Click database and select Properties. Then it will show you navigation bar with name Files. There you can check. Please upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: I selected autogrowth by 30 Percentage but still, i have the same problem - The log file for the database 'tempdb' is full. Back up the transaction log for the database to free up some log space.